# React Native - не получается настроить среду на windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mobile-development

**Скачивается у меня node версии 13 так как windows 7 выше не позволяет, но expo и cli скачиваются только при node 14 версии и выше.

Как без переезда на другую windows мне настроить среду разработки , пожалуйста подскажите если есть другие варианты...**

Comment: Docker  в вашей стране запрещен? или у проца нет поддержки

Comment: Никак, пытался как-то подготовить среду для реакта на ноутбуке (Windows 7 x32), установил последнюю возможную версию NodeJS (Как вы и сказали 13-ую), дальше попробовал установить CLI и всё никак, так что остаётся один вариант: виртуализация (VirtualBox, Qemu, VMware и подобные). Но тут уж сами смотрите, если вы хотите прям плотно работать, тогда уж лучше систему меняйте, будет намного проще, чем с виртуальной возиться.